# Jasmine: mocking Bower library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a mock for testing a service that depends on another one managed by bower. The code for the Jasmine test is the following (full example at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h9HJEj?p=preview)):

```
describe('jsonrpc', function() {
    'use strict';

    var uuidMock, $httpBackend, jsonrpc;

    beforeEach(module('jsonrpc', function ($provide) {
        uuidMock = {};
        uuidMock.generate = function () { return 0; };
        $provide.value('uuid', uuidMock);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_jsonrpc_, _$httpBackend_) {
        jsonrpc = _jsonrpc_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    it('should have created $httpBackend', function() {
        expect($httpBackend.get).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

The 'jsonrpc' service provider is defined as follows:

```
angular.module('jsonrpc', ['uuid']).provider('jsonrpc', function() {
    'use strict';

    var defaults = this.defaults = {};
    defaults.basePath = '/rpc';

    this.$get = ['$http', 'uuid4', function($http, uuid4) {
        function jsonrpc(options, config) {

        ... (etc) ...
```

When I try to mock the dependency of the 'jsonrpc' module on the 'uuid' module, I get the following error:

```
$injector:modulerr http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=jsonrpc&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Duuid%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod
```

What am I doing wrong when it comes to mock up that dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not right because you're modifying the provider of the jsrpc module, not the uuid module, and you're only calling $provide.value to provide what should be a whole module (not a value)

If uuid4 is the only part of uuid that you need to mock, you can do

```
module('jsrpc', function($provide) {
    $provide.service('uuid4', uuid4Mock)
});
```

Where uuid4Mock provides the behaviour only of that service, or whatever it is in there.